# Vim: Previous keypress too fast for mapping more than one key

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I just set this key mapping in my `.vimrc` file, however after pressing the leader key which is set to `/` it goes away almost instantly making it very hard to press `f` in time to toggle NerdTree.

```
nmap <Leader>f  <plug>NERDTreeTabsToggle<CR>
```

It's nothing like pressing `dd` which waits for the second key.

Is there somewhere I can slow it down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute following command:

```
:set notimeout
:set ttimeout
```

For more information, check out vim manual:

```
'timeout'    'ttimeout'     action
  off         off           do not time out
  on          on or off     time out on :mappings and key codes
  off         on            time out on key codes
```

—— from `:help timeout`

#### Another solution

If you just want to increase the delay of leader key, you may execute the following:

```
set timeoutlen=3000
```

Here, `3000` indicates 3 seconds, which can be set to a bigger value.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.